# Adjust volume level of individual application

Tags: volume-control

How can I adjust volume levels of individual applications? Everyone suggest using PulseAudio Volume Control, but it only allows to adjust volume of applications like video/music players, etc. How can I adjust settings of let's say BitTorrent client?

On Windows 7/8 I can easily adjust volume levels on all running applications.

Answer (score 6):

Open System settings and click Sound.

[image]

Chose the Applications tab.

[image]

Adjust individual applications.

[image]

Only the ones recently playing noises will show up. I don't know how permanent this change is.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said, it only shows 'media' type applications. Here is the screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/3PRKtnB.png. For example BitTorrent application also makes download finish sound, I want to adjust that one.

Comment: That should show it when it is playing it.

Comment: What you mean 'playing it'? It makes the quick sound when torrent finishes, and now application is running and I cannot adjust it.

Comment: I mean, during the time the sound is playing, it will appear there.

Comment: Sound is playing for like 1/5 of a second and that's it. What are you saying makes no sense.

Comment: Apologies. What I am saying was making sense, but it doesn't apply to bit torrent. (just tested) It would work on Chrome etc. Sorry.